# PyTest throws [WinError 87] parameter not found

Tags: python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, pytest

I am currently working on test automation using Python. I was trying to use Allure which, first, requires Pytest. After installing these two module, I proceeded to call:

```
pytest --alluredir $OutputPath
```

But got the **[WinError 87] parameter not found** message. In order to confirm that Allure was not causing the problem I then tried to only invoke Pytest through the Python interpreter from the command line with:

```
python -m pytest
```

But still got the same error. Looking online, this error has been happening for a while but I cannot seem to find an answer.
I'm using these versions:

**Python**-> 3.7.4

**Pytest**-> 5.2.1

**IDE**-----> Visual Studio code

**OS**-----> Windows 7

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\c.hernandezperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 54, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 167, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 196, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 89, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 76, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 981, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 1146, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 1108, in _preparse
    early_config=self, args=args, parser=self._parser
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 76, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 175, in _multicall
    next(gen)   # first yield
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 46, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround(sys.stdout)
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 711, in _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround
    sys.__stdin__ = sys.stdin = _reopen_stdio(sys.stdin, "rb")
  File "c:\users\c.hernandezperez\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 704, in _reopen_stdio
    open(os.dup(f.fileno()), mode, buffering),
OSError: [WinError 87] El parámetro no es correcto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Python 3.7.4 does not work with Pytest as stated on [this GitHub question](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5789). This question is thus considered answered.